# Trying to understand apksigner through command android

Tags: android, bash, apksigner

I am trying to generate an release apk through command. I have this below command which will sign the release apk. But I am not able to understand the commands in that. Can someone please elaborate it. Specially `/.keystore/keystore.jks` and `file:/.keystore/ks-pass`:

```
$APKSIGNER sign --ks /.keystore/keystore.jks --ks-pass file:/.keystore/ks-pass $APK_PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed in the --ks flag is the path to a keystore. A keystore contains the private key used to cryptographically sign the APK.

A keystore is guarded by a password, which can be passed to the apksigner command through the --ks-pass flag. The password can either be passed in clear if the value is prefixed with "pass:" (e.g. "pass:mypassword1234") or through the path to a file which contains the password if the value is prefixed with "file:", like in your example.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Android Studio provided tool of `generating signed apk`.

Go To:
`Build --> Generate Signed APK...` provide your `keystore path`, `keystore password`, `key alias` and `key password`.

Comment: No I want to generate a signed apk using command line only for some specific use case.